# Keyboard scroll between section

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I would like to integrate keyboard navigation in my website but I didn't manage to.

I would like to do that : http://www.demo.pagescroller.com/
When you press the "up" or "down" arrow on your keyboard the page moves between each section.

My page is structured as follows : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/Nbwgk/13/

```
<div id="page">

    <section id="home">HOME SECTION</section>

    <section id="content">
        <article class="layout">ARTICLE 1...</article>
        <article class="layout">ARTICLE 2...</article>
        <article class="layout">ARTICLE 3...</article>
        <article class="layout">ARTICLE 4...</article>
        <article class="layout">ARTICLE 5...</article>
    </section>

</div>
```

I would like that my page moves between each .

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ona Page Scroll:
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html
It's simple to usage.

Comment: Thank you. This does not work. Because in this code each section is in fullscreen. And in my page it's not like that.

Comment: Maybe this is near to you solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025603/animated-scrolling-from-anchor-to-anchor-using-the-keyboard-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if height of each section  is similar.

```
  $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 var sectionHeight=700;
 var currentScroll=$(document).scrollTop();       
 currentScroll=currentScroll-(currentScroll%sectionHeight);
 if(e.which==40)
 { 

$('html, body').animate( {
    scrollTop : (currentScroll+sectionHeight)
}, 500);

}
    else    if(e.which==38)
 {

 $('html, body').animate( {
    scrollTop : (currentScroll-sectionHeight)
}, 500);

 }
 });
```

[The updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbwgk/17/)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the function I'm looking for except that each <article> section does not necessarily 700px. I put it for example. In fact I'm trying to find a way that the page automatically moves to the next <article>.